# How to store MESH instead of Object3D in a global variable after using OBJLoader in ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am using OBJLoader inside my code to load an OBJ file but the function returns a type Object3D. I want to then perform CSG operations on the object but CSG only supports MESH not Object3D.

Is there a way to convert the Object3D file into a mesh?

```
        var bracket;
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

        //function to return a mesh from OBJ
        function objectLoader( objFile, objName ) {
            var container = new THREE.Object3D();
            loader.load( objFile , function ( object ) {
                object.name = objName;
                object.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
                container.add( object );
            })
            return container;
        }

        bracket = objectLoader('model.obj', 'Bracket');
```

I would like the '**bracket**' variable to store a mesh instead of Object3D.

I have tried directly assigning the mesh from within the function to a global variable but the mesh is not accessible outside the function unless I use a 'container', except the container returned is of Object3D type, not mesh.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to note that `loader.load()` is an asynchronous function. Let me explain:

```js
function objectLoader( objFile, objName ) {
    var container = new THREE.Object3D();

    // This function is asynchronous
    // It'll load the object and call the callback function once it's finished. 
    loader.load( objFile, function ( object ) {

        // This callback will actually fire *after* you return 'container'. 
        object.name = objName;
        object.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
        container.add( object );
    })
    
    // At this point, the container is still empty! 
    return container;
}
```

This means that you'll have to run all your code within this callback, which results in '[callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)'.

A good alternative to this is using the [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await) pattern.

Here's some modified code that'll help you get the mesh from your OBJ file. Note that `ObjectLoader` will return a `Group` which extends `Object3D`. This means you'll have to traverse this group to get the mesh(es) that you want.

```js
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

async function loadObj( objFile ) {
    const group = await loader.loadAsync( objFile );

    return group;
}

// You can only use 'await' in an async function: 
async function init() {

    // The loaded file will be a 'Group' here
    const obj = await loadObj( 'model.obj' );

    // Find the right Mesh from the obj Group
    obj.traverse(object => {
        if (object.isMesh) {
            console.log('Mesh:', object);

            // Do stuff with your mesh here, e.g.
            object.name = 'Bracket';
            object.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
        }
    })
}

init();
```